# jQuery - replaceWith to update HTML does not make image or link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

I am writing a small code with JavaScript (using jQuery and Knockout) and HTML that takes user input (GitHub username), checks if the input is valid against a GitHub api, and displays the user's GitHub avatar and username (linked to the matching profile on GitHub). The display replaces the form in which the user entered the username.

The original HTML before the user inputs is:

```
<div id="inputSection">
    <form>
        <p>
            GitHub Username:
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" id="un"/>
                <button type="button" id="submitButton">Login</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the code to replace it is this:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
    var inputForm = $(document.getElementById('inputSection'));

    $.ajax( {
        ...
        success: function () {
            alert("Welcome, " + username);
            var userURL = 'https://github.com/' + username;
            var inputContent = $('<a data-bind="attr: {href: userURL}"><img data-bind="attr: {src: avatar_url}" height=\"30\" width=\"30\"/>' + username + '</a>');
            $(inputForm.replaceWith(inputContent));
            }
    });
});
```

It seems to work for the most part. After the alert welcomes the user by username, the form disappears from the webpage. It is replaced by the username, which is formatted like a link. However, it does not function as one. Clicking it does not do anything. Also, the user's avatar, despite showing a box of the set size on the webpage, does not appear.

The solution is likely very simple and obvious, but as I only started learning these languages and libraries this week, I am not sure what is going wrong. Knockout *should* be running on the HTML page that calls the JavaScript page, and the ajax is working with regards to other functions, so I assume that's fine. The value "avatar_url" is a part of the api requested with ajax at https://api.github.com/users.

I've tried all sorts of different things to no effect. If you want any more information or have a suggestion to make this question better, please comment. I'm new to coding and Stack Overflow, but I want to make both my programs and my questions as good as possible. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**: 1. I originally failed to set a size for the image, resulting in a 0x0 image. This has been corrected, though the image itself still does not display. 2. When I first put in my code, I tried to make it easier to read by excluding where some variables had been renamed for other, unrelated portions and just making all the names match between the two relevant snippets. I did not catch them all. They should all match now.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

You’re inserting an html element with data-binds without explicitly initializing its bindings. Use `ko.applyBindings(vm, node)` on the newly injected part of the DOM.

**Long answer:**

If you're new to coding and to both jQuery and knockout, I'd suggest not using both libraries at once. Here’s why:

If you want to use knockout, you'll have to stick to a certain kind of software architecture:

> Simplify dynamic JavaScript UIs with the Model-View-View Model (MVVM) (http://knockoutjs.com/)

jQuery, on the other hand, is more of a toolbox. It doesn't dictate an architectural pattern.

> It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. (https://jquery.com/)

This might sound a bit lame, and isn't really an answer, but I'll show you the differences between solving your problem the “knockout way”, and “the jQuery way”. I’ll start with the latter, since it’s closest to your current approach:

**The jQuery approach** (note that I'm skipping the Ajax part)

Find the elements you need to make your UI interactive. Attach event listeners to buttons, modify the DOM when new data is available.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Notice that you don't need document.getElementById
  var submitButton = $("#loginButton");
  var userNameInput = $("#un");
  var inputSection = $("#inputSection");

  var getContentString = function(userName) {
    var userUrl = "https://github.com/" + userName;
    var avatarUrl = "...";

    // Inject the user specific attributes
    return "<a href=`" + userUrl + "`><img src=`" + avatarUrl + "` height='30' width='30'/>" + userName + "</a>";
  };


  var onSubmitClick = function(event) {
    var userName = userNameInput.val();
    var onSuccess = function() {
      // Create new <a> element and replace the form with the new HTML
      var inputContent = $(getContentString(userName));
      inputSection.replaceWith(inputContent);
    };

    /* 
    $.ajax({
      
      success: onSuccess
    });
    */

    //Just call onSuccess to circumvent unimplemented ajax:
    onSuccess();
  };

  submitButton.click(onSubmitClick);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inputSection">
  <p>
    GitHub Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" id="un" />
    <button type="button" id="loginButton">Login</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

**The knockout approach**

Create a viewmodel for your user. Bind the input and compute the other properties automatically. Attach event listeners through data-binds. Use `if`, `visible` or `template` bindings to swap out parts of the UI.

```js
var UserViewModel = function() {

  this.userName = ko.observable("");
  this.confirmed = ko.observable(false);

  this.userUrl = ko.computed(function() {
    return "https://github.com/" + this.userName();
  }, this);

  this.avatarUrl = ko.computed(function() {
    return "???" + this.userName();
  }, this);
};

UserViewModel.prototype.confirm = function() {
  /* ajax (disabled for example)
  $.ajax({
    success: this.confirmed.bind(null, true)
  });
  */

  this.confirmed(true);
};

var viewModel = {
  user: new UserViewModel()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: user">
  <!-- ko ifnot: confirmed -->
  <form>
    <p>
      GitHub Username:
      <input data-bind="value: userName" type="text" placeholder="username" />
      <button data-bind="click: confirm">Login</button>
    </p>
  </form>
  <!-- /ko -->

  <!-- ko if: confirmed -->
  <a data-bind="attr: { href: userUrl }">
    <img data-bind="attr: {src: avatarUrl }" />
    <span data-bind="text: userName"></span>

  </a>
  <!-- /ko -->

</div>
```

Comment: The backticks in getContentString in the long answer jQuery approach seem to be unnecessary and cause problems. I probably did something wrong when trying them. Could you please explain their function?

Comment: The back ticks were meant to be single quotes (to circumvent having to escape them). Sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

With help from user3297291's jQuery answer above, I eventually came to this. The answer was good and necessary for this progression; some parts just did not work for this situation (mostly simple compatibility issues with other code not included in this sample). Though this is a very specific question, I thought the solution should be included. Note that I have decided to stay away from Knockout for now.

The HTML suggestion to attach the id to the form rather than the div is a good move.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function inputForm() {
    var username = $("#un").val();

    function makeUserContent(user, profile, avatar) { //arguments are data from ajax
        //writes a string without the messy quotes within quotes within quotes problem
        //much clearer than trying to handle the jQuery and string all at once
        return "<a href=" + profile + "><img src=" + avatar + " height='30' width='30' />" + user + "</a>";
    }

    function submitUsername() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function correntInformation(data) {
                //data is what the ajax gets, which is passed for use
                alert("Welcome, " + username + ".");
                //calls to make the string with the data gotten by ajax
                var inputContent = $(makeUserContent(data.login, data.html_url, data.avatar_url));
                $("#inputSection").replaceWith(inputContent);
            }
        })
    }
    submitUsername();
})
```

The biggest things I took away from this problem is this: simplify strings, hold and use data, work with one library at a time (until experienced with both).